# Подготовка блока данных для передачи по TCP (char*)

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, tcp

Есть блок данных. Его необходимо передать по сети TCP и для этого конвертировать в массив char. В настоящее время сделано с использованием языка С. Код ниже

```
std::vector<char> СreateCharVector_ForWrite(complex_float *InSig, uint32_t m_LenOnePack)
{
  int32_t  sizevect=0;

  sizevect+=4; //char mark[]={'s','f','h','p'};
  sizevect+=4;//uint32_t m_LenOnePack,
  sizevect+=8*(m_LenOnePack);//размер входного массива

  sizevect+=4; // размер всего  int32_t  sizevect

  std::vector<char> m_vectDate;
  m_vectDate.resize(sizevect);//создали вектор char заданной длины

  char* buff=m_vectDate.data();

  //!Поехали писать в память
  int32_t tek_pos_char=0;


  memcpy(buff+tek_pos_char,(const char*)&sizevect,4);
  tek_pos_char+=4;

  char mark[]={'s','f','h','p'};
  memcpy(buff+tek_pos_char,(const char*)mark,4);
  tek_pos_char+=4;

  memcpy(buff+tek_pos_char,(const char*)&m_LenOnePack,4);
  tek_pos_char+=4;

  memcpy(buff+tek_pos_char,(const char*)&InSig,4*2*m_LenOnePack);

  return std::move(m_vectDate); 
}
```

Как можно сделать такое но с иcпользованием стандартной библиотеки С++.

Нашел вот такой пример

```
int main ()
{
  std::stringbuf buffer;             // empty buffer

  std::ostream os (&buffer);      // associate stream buffer to stream

  // mixing output to buffer with inserting to associated stream:
  buffer.sputn ("255 in hexadecimal: ",20);
  os << std::hex << 255;

  std::cout << buffer.str();

  return 0;
}
```

но он не нравится потому что из него непонятно как выделить буфер заданного размера и потом его заполнить.

Comment: Первый код не на C же написан

Comment: ну если memcpy уже стало с++ ....

Comment: `std::vector<char>`, `std::move()`?

Comment: Ну если вас `memcpy` смущает, используйте вместо него алгоритм  `copy` :)

Comment: меня смущает г..вно кодость подхода. Ощущения что на коленках молотком. Хотелось бы как в примере мною приведенном форматированное запихивание данных в буфер. Чувствую что есть такое. Не хочется велосипед делать по новой.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать небольшой набор функций для выполнения подобных операций. К сожалению, в данный момент не могу добраться до своего кода, но написал немного упрощенную версию того, что использую я:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class DynBuffer
{
public:
    constexpr DynBuffer(void const * buf, size_t n): buffer_(buf), size_(n) {} 
    constexpr size_t size() const { return size_; }
    constexpr void const * buffer() const { return buffer_; }
private:
    void const * buffer_;
    size_t size_;
};


template<typename T>
constexpr size_t bufferSize(T const & obj)
{
    return sizeof(obj);
}

constexpr size_t bufferSize(DynBuffer const & obj)
{
    return obj.size();
}


template<typename ... Args>
constexpr size_t evalSize(Args && ... args)
{
    return (bufferSize(args) + ...);
}


constexpr char const * rawBuffer(DynBuffer const & arg)
{
    return static_cast<char const *>(arg.buffer());
}


template<typename T>
constexpr char const * rawBuffer(T const & arg)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<char const *>(std::addressof(arg));
}


template<typename ... Args>
std::vector<char> & appendBuffersToVector(std::vector<char> & result, Args && ... args)
{
    (result.insert(result.end(), rawBuffer(args), rawBuffer(args) + bufferSize(args)), ...);
    return result;
}


template<typename ... Args>
std::vector<char> makeBuffer(Args && ... args)
{
    std::vector<char> result;
    result.reserve(evalSize(args...));    
    return appendBuffersToVector(result, args...);
}
```

С данным кодом Ваша функция превратится в нечто подобное:

```
std::vector<char> СreateCharVector_ForWrite(complex_float *InSig, uint32_t m_LenOnePack)
{
   char mark[]={'s','f','h','p'};
   auto buffer = makeBuffer(
       int32_t (), //размер пакета. Можно использовать evalSize, но в данном случае будет дублирование кода
       mark, //mark - массив, размер посчитается автоматически
       m_LenOnePack, //размер также посчитается автоматически
       DynBuffer(&InSig, 4 * 2 * m_LenOnePack)//передаем указатель и размеры "вручную", т.к. нет возможности посчитать размер автоматически
       //вы уверены, что нужно брать адрес указателя InSig?
       //скорее всего, имелось ввиду просто InSig, но я оставил как в оригинале
   );
   *reinterpret_cast<int32_t *>(buffer.data()) = buffer.size(); //записываем размер
   return buffer;//std::move не нужен здесь - он только сделает хуже
}
```

Пример использования: https://wandbox.org/permlink/4RtAJzhTeZzyiI8H